# I can't use WebStorm with React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, eslintrc

I'm trying to create a project using React but it's impossible using WebStorm, it doesn't even run. ESLint does not recognize.

1. I create a new React project using Node.js v16:

[image]

2. React project created successfully:

[image]

3. Does not run as ESLint does not recognize the constructor

[image]

4. Here's the error stack:

[image]

NOTE: I already have ESLint installed globally (`npm i -g eslint`)

P.S. I've been a WebStorm user for at least 5 years, always working with Angular, now I need to work with React. I hope I don't have to switch tools due to these details.

Comment: I've never had problems with using React with Webstorm. Try creating a blank Node project and create the app manually with CRA.

Comment: That is a WebStorm ESLint plugin problem. In newer versions of WebStorm, it should be fixed. Try upgrading your IDE.

Comment: I tried too (npx create-react-app myapp). The code is generated with success, but when I open the folder/project on Webstorm, I catch the ESlint Error when I open the index.js file.

Comment: Thanks @sean-7777, I updated my Webstorm and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Webstorm as @sean-777 suggested and now it's working fine!